Google Forms - Dropdown List
I'm developing an Employee Evaluation form, where the objective is for employees to evaluate each other. Initially, people fill in the information about which team they belong to (e.g., marketing, finance, HR, etc.), then comes the form section containing the survey, and there's an initial question with a dropdown list containing the names of all employees, where they should evaluate their fellow team members.
I've developed a code to update the options of the dropdown list in the form, but I would like this listing to be filtered according to the team selected by the employee in the previous section. Is it possible to do this using Google Apps Script? So that the dropdown list would only show the names of people from that specific team instead of showing all employees listed?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are trying to dynamically create a drop-down question where the options are names of members of a given Team; the Team is identified in a previous question.
In short, you can't do this. You can't execute any code, nor can you validate any information against an external source (including a spreadsheet) once the respondent has opened the form.
However consider this workaround:

Create a single multiple-choice "What is your Team" question.

Use the "Go to section based on answer" feature to direct control to the relevant "Team member" question.


Create multiple dropdown "Team member" questions

one for each Team
each in its own Section
direct control "after the Section" to the "Employee evaluation" section


Create a single "Employee evaluation" section containing relevant questions

The effect is that the respondent

chooses a Team,
chooses an employee within that team,
answers questions about that employee.

Changes or amendments to the content of any "Team member" question can be updated manually by script.
